# Using a small Linux as an "Ext4 server"

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, docker, samba, ext4

### Problem:

I have two external hard disks where most partitions are formatted as Ext4 to be used with my Linux workstation.

But I also have a macbook and it seems that there is almost nothing to support Ext4 file systems on MacOS.

So I thought I could create a VirtualBox virtual machine (or a docker image?) containing a Linux system such small that it should just have these components:

- capability of **mounting Ext4 partitions** on external USB drives;
- **internet connection**;
- capability to make the Ext4 partitions accessible by **creating a server**, e.g. an SSH server (to be used with SSH clients on terminal directly, or for mounting those partitions using SSHFS) or perhaps a SAMBA server.

### So the question is:

How can I create or obtain such a minimal Linux system?

Since I am only asking for the features listed above, it should be very small compared to a normal Linux distribution, perhaps just a couple hundreds megabytes or even less (I don't need any GUI, I don't need any service not directly related to the features above).

And I guess it would not be resource-consuming if such a simple virtual machine runs constantly on my Mac (or at least when I need to use the external hard disks). Am I right?

### An attempt I am making

I tried using [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/openssh-server), which points to [this repository](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-openssh-server) and is supposed to create an OpenSSH server.

I thought that once this is running, I could connect to the server using SSH and I could have mounted the Ext4 partitions in the SSH session.

I can run the docker image correctly and I can start the server, I am also able to run `sudo` commands during the SSH session (I modified the sudoers list in the docker image), but I cannot access any external USB disk (non of them, not even the non-Ext4 ones), they just do not appear in the `/dev` folder.

Comment: You can install debian netinst without a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install live linux on your VirtualBox and it should be enough, they are rather small for that very reason. There are plenty of them to choose, ([here is small list with desriptions](https://www.pcsuggest.com/best-linux-live-distro/)). I personally use [slax](https://www.slax.org/) on usb but there are others. Nothing prevents you from making your own live version that would be absolutely minimalistic after you get comfy with ready solution.

Comment: Many thanks for this suggestion, that list is very useful and it insiperd me to look for further solutions.